# iOS Charts: reduce height of grids in charts

Tags: ios, swift2, ios-charts

[image]

Hello, I want to reduce height of grids in chart, how can I?
I am using `iOS-Charts(Daniel Gindi)`.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to adjust the `barSpacing` (Charts 2.*) or `barWidth` (Charts 3.0), to change the size of the bar relative to the size of the grid strip.

The intervals of the grid are calculated dynamically, and may change when you zoom in/out, but you can constraint them also with `granularity`. This will affect the labels intervals too.